# create a link that opens a page and runs a function contained in the link

Tags: function, module, hyperlink, action, opencart

I am still learning PHP so my question may seem a little obvious but...

My question relates to opencart but is probably quite a common practice on many websites. I am creating a opencart module and in that module i have several buttons that complete different tasks. Now I have assigned the button the correct 'href' with the path and appropriate action. eg

```
$this->data['dosomething'] = $this->url->link('module/modulename/dosomething', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
```

Note: I have called the module and action a general name for the purposes of my question.

In the controller I then have a private function called 'index', followed by a private function called 'dosomething' like below

```
public function index() {

* insert code *

}

public function dosomething() {

*insert code*

$this->redirect($this->url->link('module/modulename', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));

}
```

Now, I would like to know how do I get the button to direct to the module controller and then run the 'dosomething' function. I could put something information in the link, ie action=dosomething and do it this way but most of opencart simply uses the text of the last / as the action. If I use the href stated above I get a error as it is trying to find the controller and template located in 'module/modulename/dosomething' rather than the controller and template located in 'module/modulename' USING the function 'dosomething'.

I hope this makes sense. I see that many other scripts in opencart successfully use this method but I just cant figure out how? I am sure I missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. OpenCart's framework will use the third piece of the route if specified as the method. If you try

```
public function dosomething() {
    die('OK');
}
```

Then go to the url you've got, it should just show a blank white page with `OK` written on it. My guess is the error doesn't actually relate to the controller being an issue, and more to do with something else you've done. Either that, or the method and the third part of the route aren't a match, or the `dosomething` method isn't public

Comment: Cheers, i had the 'dosomething' function as private.